# How to use HABTM fields in Active Admin filter section?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, activeadmin

I'm using Active Admin 0.3.2, and my database schema includes a few has_and_belongs_to_many relationships.  I can create and display records just fine, but attempting to include them in the **filter** section causes things to grind to a halt.

models\pin.rb:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :pin_types, :join_table => :pin_types_pins
end
```

models\pin_type.rb

```
class PinType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :pins, :join_table => :pin_types_pins
end
```

admin\pins.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Pin do
    filter :pin_types
    ...other filters
end
```

The result is that the other filters appear, but there's no section at all for Pin Types.

If admin\pins.rb is this instead:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Pin do
    filter :pin_types, :as => :check_boxes
    ...other filters
end
```

I get the following:

```
undefined method `pin_type_ids_in' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Pin:0xcd2c108>
```

What I'd like to do is allow the user to select one or many Pin Types from a set of possible choices and filter depending on whether any of the selected options apply.

Is this possible?

Comment: I found the solution myself, [on GitHub](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/515).

For reference: `filter :pin_types_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc {PinType.all}`

Comment: if we want to create Pintype from pin then what we need to do?

Answer (score 3):

use the filter like this:
filter :model_attribute
, so if you are on the User_events and wanted to search on the user name , u'd do this
filter :user_fullName

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ccarlson's answer works, but only with `:check_boxes`.

This is unfortunate, because the default behavior of meta_search (used to power the filter searching) does not filter out duplicates... and when you're using checkboxes, you probably don't want to see a result come up twice because it matches 2 selected options.

I ran into the undefined method error here when attempting to use `as: :select`, but had to bite the bullet on checkboxes.